# How to check for <null> in Swift 5 and avoid 'NSInvalidArgumentException'?

Tags: swift, null, nsnull

I'm using Swift 5.

Why does an `NSInvalidArgumentException` occur when `responseValues["CustomerID"] == '<null>'`?

Obviously the `if responseValues["CustomerID"] is NSNull` is not doing the trick. What check should be in place to avoid the `NSInvalidArgumentException`

```
self.api.getCustomerId(callback: { getIDResult in
  if let responseValues = getIDResult["ResponseValues"] {

    print("GET CUSTOMER ID RESULT")
    print(responseValues)

    if responseValues["CustomerID"] is NSNull { // <---- crashes here when null
        print("CustomerID is null")
    }
    else{
        print("CustomerID is NOT null")
    }
  }
})
```

**Succesful result**

```
GET CUSTOMER ID RESULT
{
    CustomerID = 403254;
}
CustomerID is NOT null
```

**Crashing result when encountering a null customer id**

```
GET CUSTOMER ID RESULT
{
    CustomerID = "<null>";
}
```

crashes with the following

```
019-11-21 12:13:16.819033-0500 MyApp[29412:4207932] -[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff80615710
2019-11-21 12:13:16.820557-0500 MyApp[29412:4207932] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff80615710'
```

Someone was questioning whether the value was actually null, here's some debug info on that dictionary:

[image]

Comment: Drop `SwiftyJSON` and use `Decodable`. It maps `<null>` values implicitly to `nil`. However actually this code must not crash.

Comment: your api delivers the wrong format. customerID is not nil or NULL it is a string "<null>" -> Api should fix this or you have to use a ugly string check to solve your problem in the first step

Comment: You are wrong about that smarty pants, the api is fine, it is null, NSNull to be more precise : )

Comment: :) btw. the api do not know anything about NSNull. It is a different between customerID: "null" and customerID: null

Comment: Yeah im aware the api doesnt know anything about NSNull. My problem is dealing with NSNull and NOT the string "null", to be more precise my problem is a NSInvalidArgumentException which results from this value being null

Comment: I do not get your point. You have to be clear. Maybe you could post a real json or show us your api layer implementation. Otherwise it is hard to follow up

Comment: it would be hard for me to be more clear. I'm showing the real json in my question

Comment: That may be a bug of SwiftyJSON. Avoid using such fossil-like framework.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as you!

Answer (score 0):

if responseValues is a dictionary, you can do this

```
if let customerId = responseValues["CustomerID"] as? String
{
   print(customerId)
}
else
{
   print("customer id isn't available")
}
```

if you want to know if is null, you have to change to Codable

Comment: what kind of data is getIDResult?

Comment: its a dictionary {
    CustomerID = "<null>";
}

Comment: well, can you check if the key is nill? with this code you can do it
`let keyExists = responseValues["CustomerID"] != nil
if keyExists{
    print("The key is present in the dictionary")
} else {
    print("The key is not present in the dictionary")
}`

Comment: no need to do that, I already know the key exists. null id RESULT in my question shows the dict being returned with the null value

Comment: ok, if your dictionary come from an api request, and the key exists, try this
`var result = responseValues["CustomerID"] as! Any
switch result{
case Optional<Any>.none:
    print("nil")
default:
    print("not nil")
}`

Comment: na, that also craps out with the same error. I've tried just about every cast and check and everyone fails